# Kafka won't rejoin cluster after Broken Pipe error

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster with 3 brokers and 3 zookeepers. Based on the Kafka server.log, it intermittently encounter broken pipe error for some unknown reason. After the broken pipe error gone, instead of rejoin the cluster the Kafka broker decide to stay out of cluster and become its own leader (since it shrinks the ISR from 3 to 1).

So far the only workaround is to restart the broker and it will rejoin cluster normally as a follower. But we can't keep restarting manually every time a similar issue appear.

```
[2019-05-10 10:32:48,344] WARN Failed to send SSL Close message  (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:718)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:746)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:734)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:532)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:628)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2019-05-10 10:32:48,368] WARN Failed to send SSL Close message  (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:718)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:746)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:734)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:532)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:628)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2019-05-10 10:32:53,422] WARN Failed to send SSL Close message  (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:718)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:746)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:734)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:532)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:628)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2019-05-10 10:32:56,976] INFO [Partition CS_NL_CUSTOMER_ADD-1 broker=4] Shrinking ISR from 4,6 to 4 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-05-10 10:32:56,994] INFO [Partition CS_NL_CUSTOMER_ADD-1 broker=4] Cached zkVersion [24394] not equal to that in zookeeper, skip updating ISR (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-05-10 10:32:56,994] INFO [Partition _confluent-controlcenter-5-1-0-1-MetricsAggregateStore-changelog-3 broker=4] Shrinking ISR from 4,6 to 4 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-05-10 10:32:57,023] INFO [Partition _confluent-controlcenter-5-1-0-1-MetricsAggregateStore-changelog-3 broker=4] Cached zkVersion [3724] not equal to that in zookeeper, skip updating ISR (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-05-10 10:32:57,023] INFO [Partition TEST_3_PART-2 broker=4] Shrinking ISR from 4,6 to 4 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-05-10 10:32:57,033] INFO [Partition TEST_3_PART-2 broker=4] Cached zkVersion [3300] not equal to that in zookeeper, skip updating ISR (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

As far as I understand about Kafka, isn't Kafka broker supposedly to rejoin itself to cluster whenever possible? Why it isn't happening after got broken pipe error?
One more thing is, any idea what caused Broken Pipe error? Is it network issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's something wrong with the certificates. You need to issue a signed certificate for the broker(s) and add it in your client's keystore.

Confluent's guide on how to configure [Encryption and Authentication with SSL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html) should make things more clear.

Comment: You mean the broken pipe connection is between the broker and the client? If that so, then what caused the broker to walk out from the cluster?